# Remote Access to MSSQL Database with Plesk

Tags: sql-server, networking, tcp

I'm struggling to get a remote connection to a database running on a Cloud VM running Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2014 Express.

I can connect locally on the machine (thorugh RDP) using SQL Server Management Studio. I have also right-clicked through SQL Managment Studio and checed that allow remote connections is enabled.

As I mentioned the server is running plesk, so I have enable the following firewall rules;

> MS SQL over TCP protocol  Allow incoming connections from all on port
>   1433/TCP, profiles: domain,private,public

and

> MS SQL Probe  Allow
>   incoming connections from all on port 1434/UDP, profiles:
>   domain,private,public

I have double checked this with the windows firewall and it seems to be allowing the connections through.

Next, I have (through SQL Configuration Manager) done the following;

SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER

Enabled TCP/IP
Enabled Named Pipes

Under the TCP/IP properties I have IP2 enabled and active, with the IP Address being the public static ip pointng to the server, TCP Dynamic ports is empty and TCP Port is 1433.

IPALL has TCP Dynamic Ports blank, and TCP Port is 1433.

I have restarted the SQL Services, and the instance is running as MSSQLSERVER.

I have then tried to connect remotely through SQL Management Studio (and VS 2013).

Through SQL Management Studio I get the following error;

> A network related or instance-specific error occurred whilst
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsfot SQL Server, Error: 53).

(I use the server IP and the Server Name, i.e. I am not specifiying an instance or port here and I use the same credentials as I have logged in with locally).

Comment: From a remote machine, do you get any response if you try to telnet to the server on port 1433, or does that simply time out?  For example, if you were to use the Windows telnet client to do this ("telnet <serverIP> 1433" from a command prompt), you would get a blank window with a blinking cursor or something like that if you can reach the server and some service is listening on that port.  If you aren't reaching the server or something is blocking you, it should time out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem as you did just now. I solved it by adding a new firewall rule on top of the existing Plesk rule within Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.

For testing purposes when I first set up the rule, I didn't restrict IP access; that allowed to verify that the rule was set up correctly when I accessed SQL Server remotely. I restricted it to remote IPs after that. I was working with Windows Server 2008, but it should work for 2012 as well.